Some symbol definitions not passed to parallel kernels
In a notebook, I globally define a symbol named x1, for instance
x1=99

I then define a function in which a local variable named xLoc is assigned the value of x1 in the following way :
someFunction[]:=Module[{xLoc,i},
...
i=1;
xLoc=Symbol["x"<>ToString[i]]; 
...
];

When executed locally, no problem and the symbol xLoc is assigned the value of 99. But, when executed in parallel I have to explicitly say
DistributeDefinitions[x1]

or the symbol xLoc is assigned the value x1 and not 99...
Does anyone understand this behavior ? Obviously, it has to do with the use of Symbol[] as a way of defining xLoc...
